# openURL in safari. Phishing warning

Tags: ios, xcode, safari

I want to open a url from my app in safari, however the url page requires login details and i'd rather pass these details automatically so the page just opens.
If I add the login details to the URL eg. `http://user:pass@myurl.com` it opens in safari but I get an anti phishing warning.

Is there an alternative way to avoid getting the warning?

Thanks

Comment: Load it in a webview inside your app, then use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method of UIWebView to run some javascript, detect the correct login div tag id's and insert the details this way.

Comment: Is there no way to use safari instead of a web view?

Comment: None that I am aware of - also not sure Apple would approve of this. My method above was used in an enterprise app for a client - think you'd be fine for public as well, eg if it was feeding off a user's previously input details, or retrieved from the keychain/plist etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. That means I have to go through adding back buttons, progress bar etc.. I guess i'll have to, unless you know of any drop in class that has everything needed for a webview?

Comment: There will be a few on here that you could use: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=browser else just create a UIViewController, add a UIWebView and UIToolbar you're nearly there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a php redirect like this it should work:

```
<?php
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302)
  {
     header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
     die();
  }
$url = 'https://' . $_REQUEST['user'] . ':' . $_REQUEST['password'] . '@myurl.com';
redirect($url);
?>
```

name that php file 'login.php'
possible html page:

```
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
username<input type='text' name='user'><br>
password<input type='password' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' value='login'>
</form>
```

or open the page:

`https://myurl.com/login.php?user=[some script to get username]&password=[password]`

these answers would require creating files on the server. I'm not sure if you own the domain or not but these files should work on any server with php and could easily redirect to any website.

hope this helps